# Check is JSON is valid

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to get JSON in a valid format so that it can be sent to an API and I can't figure out why the below JSON is not valid.  Please can someone explain why this is not valid?

```js
{
    "Description": "test",
    "Quantity": "0.30",
    "UnitAmount": "6400.0",
    "TaxType": "OUTPUT2",
    "AccountCode": "200"
}, 
{
    "Description": "test2",
    "Quantity": "0.30",
    "UnitAmount": "0.0",
    "TaxType": "OUTPUT2",
    "AccountCode": "200"
}
```

Comment: They should be in an array (`[...]`).

Comment: Try using json validators like https://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top level of a JSON text must be one of the JSON data types (like object, array, or string).

There can only be one data type at the top level.

You have an object but then you have a comma and then a second object.

Perhaps you should wrap it in an array.

Comment: Not really worth an answer... Voted to close as not repro  - comments to question answers